# Send request with equivalent to Python's bytes() in Node.js

Tags: node.js, axios, request, byte

I'm looking to send a request in Node.js which requires sending the data in byte format.

In python, I've implemented it as follow:

```
r = requests.post(url="https://example.com",headers=headers, data=bytes(exampleArray))
```

The type of exampleArray is uint8 array

Is it possible to do  this same post in Node.js, potentially with axios or another module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios accepts a [variety](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) of formats as payload. This is an example with an `Uint8Array` array:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const data = new TextEncoder().encode(
  JSON.stringify({
    foo: 'bar',
  })
);

axios
  .post('http://localhost:3001', data)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(`Status: ${res.status}`);
    console.log('Body: ', res.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

The same applies to the `http(s)` module

```
const http = require('http');

const data = new TextEncoder().encode(
  JSON.stringify({
    foo: 'bar',
  })
);

const options = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 3001,
  path: '/',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length,
  },
};

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error);
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```